# XSLT - Traverse through root node

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the XML structure as below

I am deep down in the inner elements of env:Envelope and want to jump to something in Report_Entry.

I tried multiple paths like *, .., . and more but was not able to get to the expected node.
The `<xsl:for-each select="/*">` is taking me to the root but `<xsl:for-each select="/*/wd:Report_Entry">` does NOT work

```
  <root>
    <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Child1>
        <Child2>
            <Child3>
            </Chiild3>
        </Child2>
    </Child1>
    </env:Envelope>
    <wd:Report_Entry xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR_INT001_Worker_Benefit_Group>
    <Child4>
        <Child5>
        </Child5>
    </Child4>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</root>
```

Here are the XSLT declarations

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    xmlns:out="http://www.workday.com/integration/output"
    xmlns:func="http://www.func.com"
    xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt" 
    xmlns:env="urn:com.workday/bsvc" wd:version="v35.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs wd out xsl xtt func">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>      
    <xsl:template match="/root">    
        <Root>
     <-- I am in Chiild 3 and want to retrieve the value from Child 5-->
        </Root>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

Any help appreciated

Comment: If you have the right namespace declarations your path `/*/wd:Report_Entry` seems to be correct. So consider to show a minimal but complete sample to allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MartinHonnen This is my sample XML   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<root>
    <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <Child1>
  <Child2>
   <Child3>
   </Chiild3>
  </Child2>
 </Child1>
    </env:Envelope>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
 <Child4>
  <Child5>
  </Child5>
 </Child4>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</root>
   My XSLT namespace declarations at the top

Comment: Please edit the question and insert both a minimal but complete XML as well as the XSLT there as well-formatted code samples.

Comment: The question is updated with the XML.
Somehow I need to move from inner child of  env:Envelope to an inner child of wd:Report_Entry
Thanks

Comment: Minimal but complete samples to allow us to reproduce the problem still are missing. Or how do you expect any XML parser to parse `<wd:Report_Entry xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR_INT001_Worker_Benefit_Group>` or how do you expect us to tell whether the XSLT has the right namespace declarations if you don't show that part of the XSLT?

Comment: Have updated the namespaces I am using.

Comment: The namespace used in the XSLT for prefix `wd` doesn't seem to be the same namespace in the XML input for the `Report_Entry` element.